# Adding a tag to all images in a docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For all my images I have a `latest` tag for production, and `test` for testing. I also have 2 docker-compose files that only differ in that one uses `latest` on all packages (except nginx), while the other uses `test`. Is there a way to set this via a CLI variable, so that I don't have to keep those two files in sync manually all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can handle this with an environment variable.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  ...
  my-service-one:
    image: my/service-one:$TAG
    ...
  my-service-two:
    image: my/service-two:$TAG
    ...
```

Then we can add an [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) (for production) with content

```
TAG=latest
```

and a `test.env` file (for testing) with content

```
TAG=test
```

When we run `docker compose up`, file `.env` will be used by default. If we want to start our test deployment, we can run [`docker compose --env-file test.env up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option).

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to set a default that happens when there is no .env file?

Comment: The `.env` file is the default.

Comment: @DottyPhone If I get what you are really looking for is **${VARIABLE:-default}**, else you can refer to this Documentation [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run these commands for each compose file

```sh
TAG=latest docker-compose -p latestapp -f compose-for-latest.yaml up -d
```

and

```sh
TAG=test docker-compose -p testapp -f compose-for-test.yaml up -d
```

of course, don't forget to specify where you want to use your Tag variable in the compose files using `${TAG}` or `$TAG` **(BOTH ARE VALID)**

> If you are a LINUX user this should work fine.

> if you are a WINDOWS user and the commands didn't work you can use GIT BASH instead.